# Neo4j - Cypher return 1 to 1 relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using neo4j 1.9.2, I'm trying to find all nodes in my graph that have a one to one relationship to another node. Let's say I have persons in my graph and I would like to find all persons, that have exactly one friend (since 2013), and this one friend only has the other person as friend and no one else. As a return, I would like to have all these pairs of "isolated" friends.

I tried the following:

```
START n=node(*) MATCH n-[r:is_friend]-m-[s:is_friend]-n
WHERE r.since >= 2013 and s.since >= 2013
WITH n, m, count(r), count(s)
WHERE count(r) = 1 AND count(s) = 1
RETURN n, m
```

But this query does not what it is supposed to do - it simply returns nothing.

Note: There exists just one relation between the two persons. So one friend has a incoming relationship and the other one an outgoing one. Also, these two persons might have some other relations, like "works_in" or so, but I just want to check if there is a 1:1 relation of type *is_friends* between the persons.

**EDIT:** The suggestion of Stefan works perfect if using node(*) as starting point. But when trying this query for one specific node as start point (e.g. start n=node(42)), it doesn't work. What would the solution look like in this case?

**Update:** I'm still wondering about a solution for this szenario: How to check if a given start node has a 1-to-1 relation to another node of a specific relationship type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here it's crucial to understand the concept of paths in the `MATCH` clause. A path is a alternating collection of node, relationship, node, relationship, .... node. There is the constraint that the same relationship will never occur twice in the same path - otherwise there would be a danger of having endless loops.

That said, you need to decide if `is_friend` in your domain is directed. If it is directed you'd distinguish a being friend to b and b being friend to a. From the description I assume `is_friend` is undirected and the statement should look like:

```
START n=node(*) MATCH n-[r:is_friend]-()
WHERE r.since >= 2013
WITH n, count(r) as numberOfFriends
WHERE numberOfFriends=1
RETURN n
```

You don't have to care about the other end, it's traversed nonetheless since you do a `node(*)`. Be aware that `node(*)` gets obviously more expensive when your graph grows.

Comment: Ok, you are right, when starting from node(*) your suggestion is working fine. But how would I do this when starting from a single start node? Then the constraint, that the friend has only one friend is not checked. To be honest, what I actually do is starting from a subset of the graph. But still, for this case your suggestion does not return all I isolated friends in the whole graph

Comment: What about my edit? When starting from one specific start node, how can I check if this start node has only one friend and this one friend has only the start node as friend and returning both of the nodes if this is the case. Any suggestions about that scenario?

Comment: You can use a optional `match`: `MATCH n-[r?:is_friend]-()`, note the question mark after `r`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this helps.Trying it as follows does not check if the friend of the start node has only the start node as friend (and no additional other friends). Note: I am starting from a specific start node, here node 42.



    `START n=node(42) MATCH n-[r?:is_friend]-()
    WHERE r.since >= 2013
    WITH n, count(r) as numberOfFriends
    WHERE numberOfFriends=1
    RETURN n`

Comment: This really seems to do the trick! Even though I actually planed to return both of the friends (WITH n, m, collect(..)), starting from just a single start node. But in this case I simply reuse the results in a second query. Thank you @jjaderberg !